# CORS in asp.net core 2.1 and angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

There is quite a lot of discussions on this subject, however none is working for me. I have a asp.net core api 2.1 with an angular 7 app.

Error:

> "fleet:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://localhost:44354/api/test' from origin 'http://localhost:4200'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource."

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme.AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.AddCors((options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AzurePolicy", builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
         );
    }));

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("AzurePolicy");
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Config:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xx.com",
    "TenantId": "xx",
    "ClientId": "xx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I even added following to controller:

```
 [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
```

Is there more things you can do here?

Comment: Where is your "AzurePolicy" policy defined? `app.UseCors("AzurePolicy");`?

Comment: You need to understand what you are doing (what cors is and how it works) For instance allow any origin is not compatible with allowcredentials, and you really should know why if you are developing this kind of systems.

Comment: @juan I was trying to follow this article. https://adrianszen.com/2019/02/19/angular-with-azure-active-directory-authentication-adal-angular4/ You have to start somewhere. You have a proposal on how to solve it?

Comment: @Juan I tried removing AllowCredentials then I get 401. If you have any input it is appreciated.

Comment: 401 means you are missing authentication, because by not allowing credentials, nor cookies nor Authentication header is sent to the server. The thing is you can't send these to the server having allow any origin. You need to lock down the origin to your specific url in order to allow credentials. This is not the only thing you will find along the road, start here, it will help you troubbleshootin whatever comes up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks. Read the article. So I am using a bearer token, I am not sure how asp.net translate that in the code I pasted (AllowCredentials). When I look in the it looks like an working sample, not sure what differ for me. Do you have any idea, that in the asp.net part that needs to be corrected? One think is knowing CORS another thing is hos asp.net works accordig to CORS.

Comment: I actually got a little further. I removed the https url so I only had one as you described. Now I get another error must be related to the way I have setup azure. Have to do some more digging. HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Vary: Origin
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcU2VnYXRvXERldmVsb3BtZW50XEhhZm5pYUNoYXJ0ZXJpbmdcY2hhcnRlcmluZ1xBUElcQ2hhcnRlcmluZy5BUElcQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AzureActiveDirectory` settings in **appsettings.json**

Like this:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "Domain": "AD_DOMAIN",
  "TenantId": "TENANT_GUID",
  "ClientId": "APPLICATIONID_GUID"
}
```

For more details, follow this [Article](https://adrianszen.com/2019/02/19/angular-with-azure-active-directory-authentication-adal-angular4/)

Comment: Kind of funny, it's exactly that article I use. I have the config file as described. What do you add here ?  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("SHOULDNT THIS BE NAME OF CONFIG. That is AzureAd", options))? Same applies here what string d you add there? options.AddPolicy("ALSO AzureAd?")?